# Cannot read property 'transition' null chartjs

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, chart.js

I have a dynamic data that is need to be put inside a for loop in order to display the data of interest. I tested putting animation into 0 from this [issue](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/5149) and also try the same update() function.

This is my code below

```
barChartMonth() {
  let backgroundColor: any = [
    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
  ];

  let borderColor: any = [
    'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
    'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
  ];


  this.barChart = new Chart(this.barCanvas.nativeElement, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: this.monthcostlabor,
    },
    options: {
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        }]
      }
    }
  });
  for(let bard = 0; bard < this.monthcostlabor.length; bard++){
    this.barChart.data.datasets.push({ label: this.monthcostlabor[bard], backgroundColor: backgroundColor[bard], borderColor: borderColor[bard], borderWidth: 1 });
  }
  this.barChart.data.datasets.forEach(element => {
    element.data.push(this.monthcostglobal)
  });
  this.barChart.update();
}
```

The code above dynamically choose color, hover and based on the data recorded. See for loop. Is there any other way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few of the glaring problems is how the length of `backgroundColor` and `borderColor` could be less than `this.monthcostlabor` leading to `undefined` values when loaded through the `bard` iterator.

Also, why cannot you loop within the constructor?

```
this.barChart = new Chart(this.barCanvas.nativeElement, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: this.monthcostlabor,
    datasets: this.monthcostlabor.map((elem,i) => ({ 
         label: elem, 
         backgroundColor: backgroundColor[(i % backgroundColor.length)], 
         borderColor: borderColor[(i % borderColor.length)], 
         borderWidth: 1, 
         data:[this.monthcostglobal] })); // the second push() can be included here?    
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});

/*
  for(let bard = 0; bard < this.monthcostlabor.length; bard++){
  this.barChart.data.datasets.push({ label: this.monthcostlabor[bard], backgroundColor: backgroundColor[bard], borderColor: borderColor[bard], borderWidth: 1 });
}
this.barChart.data.datasets.forEach(element => {
  element.data.push(this.monthcostglobal)
});
this.barChart.update(); */
```

Comment: the monthcostlabor data  is this = [February,June]
and monthcostglobal is this = [2550,4200]
still doesnt show the output

the background color and border color I assume it that it will always have max values in array

Comment: I didnt think that i can loop through constructor I also a beginner

Comment: 1 more thing ,how can i have only the left side bar graph please see image [image](https://imgur.com/a/hETJTmv)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is related to async api calls

I solved it with :

```
  async setChart () {
    this.myChart = await this.apiService.setChartData(this.myChart, this.myCanvas);
    this.myChart.update();
  }


  async this.apiService.setChartData(mChart, mCanvas) {
    mChart.data = this.getChrData(mLabel, dtSets, this.colourList, this.colourBordList, cType);
    mChart.data.labels = mLabel;
    return mChart;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Same issue was happened to me. I resolved it using a setTimeout(function(){chart.update()},50) but your solution is more elegant.
Nice